# AppSync Schema Design

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I am fairly new to AppSync and i have been trying to understanding the in and outs of the relational models.

I have the following requirement where my App has the follow schema type Users, Posts and Events.

1. A User should only be able to make a single post.
2. A Post must be owned by only one User but also have multiple Editors.
3. A Event must have a single post and only two users at any given time.

Could some one provide a possible schema design that could achieve these requirements please

Answer (score 0):

Our tutorials for DDB sound like the primer you need to learn schema design for Appsync (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-resolvers.html).

I would also recommend learning standard graphQL becuase that is what Appsync implements and the relational models stem from graphQL.